# Java Facebook Messenger webhook get user's user agent and ip address

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jersey, webhooks

I am developing an application that accepts facebook's messages and registered as a consumer for FB messaging webhook. I can see lot of parameters there but can't see user's ip address and user's user-agent string. Are those parameters available there and if so, how to take them?

```
    @Path(value = "/webhook")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postAccept(String str) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        logger.info("Input string:" + str);
       //need to have ip and user-agent params here
        MessageWrapper src = gson.fromJson(str, MessageWrapper.class);
        try {
            if (src.getObject().equals("page")) {
                src.getEntry().forEach(entry -> {
                    logger.info("Entry:" + entry);
                    entry.getMessaging().forEach(e -> {
                        this.dispatchMessage(entry, e);
                    });
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error", e);
            return Response.ok(src).build();
        }

        return Response.ok(src).build();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need them? No you can not get them

Comment: Thanks, I need it because my employer wants to have statistics how many users from different countries user this messenger, etc

Comment: Ok. As I said you can't get them